# Include python file and library in Java

Tags: java, python

I am using Python within a Java project.
I have Java class `demo.java` and Python method `test.py`

## demo.java

```
public class myJavaClass{
    public String myMethod() {
        PythonInterpreter interpreter = new PythonInterpreter();
        //Code to write
    }
 }
```

## test.py

```
import cv2
def abc():
   image = cv2.imread(argv[0])
   print(image.shape)
```

The problem I don't know where cv2 library, Python compiler in Java structure folder? And I want to to call the `abc()` method of my Python file from the `test` method of my Java file and print the result.

Comment: Are you looking for the top directory location of your Java project on your file system? Usually it is located in your user directory: HuyVuThe/workspace/<your_java&python_project>.

Comment: @Patrick I want to include Python module and library within Java project